# Why do you have 'where' when there is 'having'

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having-clause

I know this is much discussed, but none of my research could convince me the difference between '`where`' and '`having`' clauses in MySQL. From what I understand we can achieve everything that can be done with 'where' clause using '`having`' . For eg. `select * from users having username='admin'`. Then why do you need '`where`' clause? Does using where make any performance differences?

Comment: see also: [SQL - having VS where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244); [WHERE vs HAVING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause filters data from the source before aggregates, whereas `HAVING` clause filters data after the `GROUP BY` has been applied. Generally this means any non-aggregate filter can appear in either place, but if you have a column that is not referenced in your query, you can only filter it in a `WHERE` clause.

For example, if you have the following table:

```
| ID | VALUE |
--------------
|  1 |    15 |
|  2 |    15 |
|  3 |    20 |
|  4 |    20 |
|  5 |    25 |
|  6 |    30 |
|  7 |    40 |
```

Suppose you wanted to apply the following query:

```
select value, count(value)
from Table1
group by value
```

But you only wanted to include rows where `ID > 2`. If you put that in a `HAVING` clause, you will get an [**error**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6741/17), because the `ID` column is not available post aggregate as it is not in the `SELECT` clause.  In that case, you would be required to use a `WHERE` clause instead:

```
select value, count(value)
from Table1
where id > 2
group by value
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6741/16

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `HAVING` from `WHERE` clause is that `HAVING` supports aggregated columns while `WHERE` doesn't because it is only applicable for individual rows., EG

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1  --- <<== HERE
```

---

From the MySQL docs,

*"You may use Alias's if you use HAVING instead of WHERE this is one of the defined differences between the two clauses. Having is also slower and will not be optimized, but if you are placing a complex function like this in your where you obviously aren't expecting great speed."*

Comment: Thanks. But I know the difference.why do you need to use where when everything can be achieved using having clause ?

Comment: in your example they do the same thing but if you are a good sql developer you should know where to use both keywords. `WHERE` is evaluated first before the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: From the MySQL docs, *"You may use Alias's if you use HAVING instead of WHERE this is one of the defined differences between the two clauses. Having is also slower and will not be optimized, but if you are placing a complex function like this in your where you obviously aren't expecting great speed."*

Answer (score 1):

Where evaluates on the single row level, whereas having is used for group by expressions.

Answer (score 1):

With the `HAVING` clause, you can specify a condition to filter **groups** as opposed to filtering **individual**
rows, which happens in the `WHERE` phase. 
Only groups for which the logical expression in the `HAVING`
clause evaluates to TRUE are returned by the `HAVING` phase . Groups for which the logical expression evaluates to `FALSE or UNKNOWN` are filtered out.

When `GROUP BY` is not used, `HAVING` behaves like a `WHERE` clause .
Regarding performance comparison please see this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)