# syntax error near WHERE when trying to find product with names that are different with the same assigned codes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have columns in a table product named id and name. Each row is a product with a single product code.

I would like to retrieve the names and IDs of similar-sounding products with different codes. Anyone know what the basic structure of such a query should look like in mySQL?

Comment: I think you were meaning to use the [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) keyword instead of the last `WHERE` clause (ie, `HAVING COUNT(products.id) > 1`)

Comment: are you missing a join condition

Answer (score 0):

Your last where clause should be a HAVING clause, not a where clause.  You are using an aggregate function on a row-level filter.

See [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

Answer (score 0):

the following query gives you the name of the products repeated 2 or more times:

```
select name, count(*) from product group by name having count(*) > 1;
```

the following gives you the name of the products:

```
slect name from (select name, count(*) from product group by name having count(*) > 1) as many_codes;
```

and finally the following should give you the result you are looking for:

```
select name, id from product where name in (slect name from (select name, count(*) from product group by name having count(*) > 1) as many_codes);
```