# Issue with HAVING in SQL query

Tags: mysql

Imagine table with two columns (there are more, but not relevant anyhow to this question):

```
  `EAN` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameter_id` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

This query does not work and returns error:

```
SELECT EAN FROM eTovar WHERE EAN GROUP BY EAN HAVING parameter_id IS NULL
```

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'parameter_id' in 'having
>   clause'

But this query works:

```
SELECT EAN FROM eTovar WHERE EAN GROUP BY EAN HAVING MIN(parameter_id) != MAX(parameter_id)
```

I assume that for some reason, HAVING is able to reach MIN(parameter_id) but unable to reach clean parameter_id. **Why?**

I have MariaDB 5.5 (should be same as MySQL 5.5).

Comment: It might be a bit more helpful if you would provide your SQL schema. (might be something to think about for the future at least)

Comment: I did not think it is necessary, since it is only two columns, but here you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MySQL 5.5 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the HAVING clause that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. A MySQL extension permits references to such columns to simplify calculations. This extension assumes that the nongrouped columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise, the result is indeterminate.
>   [...]
>   In some cases, you can use MIN() and MAX() to obtain a specific column value even if it is not unique.

Have you tried replacing `HAVING` with `WHERE` in your first SQL:

```
SELECT EAN FROM eTovar WHERE EAN AND parameter_id IS NULL GROUP BY EAN;
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing. Using WHERE instead of HAVING works for me with similarly constructed queries using MySQL Workbench on an InnoDB table.

Comment: If I put `parameter_id IS NULL` into `WHERE`, it will be filtered out in `HAVING`

Comment: I guess I just have to put `parameter_id` when selecting columns and than remove column later...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELECT EAN FROM eTovar WHERE EAN AND parameter_id IS NULL GROUP BY EAN` ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - yes, indeed.

Comment: @Martin are you saying you need to use `HAVING` for some reason? Is `parameter_id` a field or a property of the aggregation? [Having vs Where](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9253267/4243498)

Comment: I want to get list of `EAN` which have `EAN` same as some other record while they do not have same `parameter_id` + or `parameter_id` is `NULL`.

Comment: I want to group records with `parameter_id`. Two similar product have same `parameter_id`. I am joining products together when they have same `EAN` but they are not yet joined using `parameter_id`. There is more different reasons why products have same `parameter_id`, `EAN` is one of them.

Comment: @ChipsLetten I was visualising `HAVING` only as "another `WHERE`", thanks for [Having vs Where]. That explains why it can not see `parameter_id`.