# Doctrine QueryBuilder: avg returns string value, not numeric

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't filter my results with `andHaving` condition, because `AVG` function returns string values.

```
 $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Service')->createQueryBuilder('s');
 $qb->join('s.ratingList', 'r')
    ->addSelect('AVG(r.rating) as avg_rating')
    ->addGroupBy('s.service')
    ->andHaving('avg_rating >= :rating')
    ->setParameter('rating', $rating)
  ;
```

In results see that `avg_rating` is string format not number, that's why filtering doesn't work. Now how can I get `avg_rating` as integer?

Comment: having and where are different things. please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where

Comment: I know difference, but the problem is that parameter is not setting.

Comment: Now, change having with where and see that parameter works or not. That's why i mention these are different.

Comment: if I do what you advised I have : `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "sclr_8" in "where clause"` (sclr_8 - i guess is avg_rating)

Comment: try `->where('AVG(r.rating) >= :rating')`

Comment: @VaN it didn't work