# SQL group by count where count greater than

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this SQL that counts the groups, but I want to say where the count is greater than 1, can anyone help as it doesn't currently work?

```
select Code, Qty, Count(Qty) from Product where ItemName = 'Banana'
and Count(Qty) > 1
Group by Code, Qty order by 3 desc
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant to group by `Qty`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - having VS where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should put this condition in the `HAVING`-clause:

```
select Code, Qty, Count(Qty) Qty
from Product 
where ItemName = 'Banana'
Group by Code
having count(Qty) > 1
order by 3 desc
```

`HAVING` is evaluated after `GROUP BY` while `WHERE` is evaluated before, meaning that `WHERE`-clauses will filter on recordlevel while `HAVING`-clauses filter on aggregates.

For a more detailed explanation, check [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

I would also recommend you to read [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Comment: Didn't see you answered before me. Since our answers are pretty much the same, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours.

Comment: Then we have 2 columns that have same name `Qty`