# Sql COUNT with HAVING clause producing wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Record in my mysql database

```
id  camper_id   reg_date
1   3           2017-04-17 00:00:00
2   3           2017-04-18 00:00:00
3   4           2017-04-15 00:00:00
4   4           2017-04-13 00:00:00

SELECT COUNT(*),camper_id,reg_date FROM tbl_registration GROUP BY camper_id HAVING reg_date >= CURDATE()
```

lets say today or CURDATE is 2017-04-15 00:00:00

I am getting the wrong result This is what I get when I run the query

```
COUNT(*)    campr_id    reg_date
2           3           2017-04-15 00:00:00
2           4           2017-04-18 00:00:00
```

I should be getting..

```
COUNT(*)    camper_id   reg_date
2           3           2017-04-15 00:00:00
1           4           2017-04-18 00:00:00
```

what is wrong with my query ?

Comment: What if you pull the `GROUP BY` part as the last one ? And why don't use `WHERE` clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), camper_id, reg_date
FROM tbl_registration
GROUP BY camper_id
HAVING reg_date >= CURDATE();
```

The `HAVING` is processed *after* the `GROUP BY`.  But you have not specified `reg_date` in the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, you should have an aggregation function around it.

I think you really want a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), camper_id, MIN(reg_date) as reg_date
FROM tbl_registration
WHERE reg_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY camper_id;
```

MySQL allows you to have such "bare" columns in an aggregation.  However, it is a really bad practice.  I think the most recent version of MySQL has changed the default behavior to not allow this construct -- conforming better to ANSI SQL and to how other databases work.

Comment: Your query produces the required result when I run it directly in PhpMyadmin but when I use the same query in php code it produces the  Undefined index: COUNT(reg_date) error

Comment: Thank you its working fine after modifying a it at my end. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       camper_id,
       reg_date
FROM tbl_registration
WHERE DATEDIFF( reg_date,
                CURDATE() ) >= 0
GROUP BY camper_id;
```

Please read dasblinkenlight's answer at [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where) for an excellent discussion of the difference between `WITH` and `HAVING`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I get unexpected ordering of clauses (near GROUP BY) in PhpMyadmin

Comment: Your query also producing the required result. Thank you too as wel and I appreciate the link for the discussion .