# Hive Failed SemanticException

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

```
Hive vertion:apache-hive-2.3.0
hive> select TAG_EMOTION_KEY AS key,count(1) AS cnn from NB_ORDER_RATE_EMOTION t  where t.cnn>10 group by TAG_EMOTION_KEY ;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:84 Invalid column reference 'cnn'
```

what's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to get list of `TAG_EMOTION_KEY` which has appeared more then 10. For that you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` clause.

Like:

```
select
    TAG_EMOTION_KEY AS key,
    count(1) AS cnn
from
    NB_ORDER_RATE_EMOTION t
group by
    TAG_EMOTION_KEY
having
    count(1) > 10
;
```

Following question provides the difference between `HAVING` & `WHERE` clause: [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

Comment: Tks, i want to know does HIVE support Alias?  For example: "select TAG_EMOTION_KEY AS key,count(1) from NB_ORDER_RATE_EMOTION t group by t.key"    -----It does'nt work.