# Sql count and and/or condition in single statement

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to build `where` clause condition on table having columns “Id”, itemNumber” which can be either 1 or 2 for any row and “date”.

My goal is to write where clause such that i only get “Id’s” where “itemNumber” is 2, and then if count is greater than some value it should filter whole rows to date between today and today+1, otherwise today and today+2.

I tried,

```
Select Id  
from table 
where itemNumber=2 And ((count(itemNumber)>2 and date between ‘today’ and ‘today+1’) OR (count(itemNumber)<=2 and date between ‘today’ and ‘today+2’))
```

I got error saying you need to have sql “having”. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: You use aggregate functions.  `WHERE` is for pre-aggregation conditions, `HAVING` - for post-aggregation.  Since results of `COUNT` are known only after aggregation is completed - you need `HAVING`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

Comment: Learn about `GROUP BY` here  https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE itemNumber = 2
GROUP BY id
HAVING (COUNT(itemNumber) > 2 AND date BETWEEN 'today' and 'today+1'))
OR (COUNT(itemNumber) <= 2 AND date BETWEEN 'today' and 'today+2'))
```

Think of HAVING as a WHERE clause after you have grouped your data, which you have to do if you want to count something by group (or id).

Comment: I think I phrased my question wrong. The column “Id” is primary key, but i am having one more column “Id1” which can be duplicated. So, my goal is to select all “Id”, with where condition what i mentioned. Since i am selecting “Id”, i have to use that column in “group by” and my rows are not grouping since there can be only one row for one Id as it is primary key. So having all conditions are becoming useless.

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannam sounds like something we can resolve. Some sample data would help, though, to understand exactly what you mean

Comment: ID ID1 itemNumber date                                                                                                                                        
1 1 1 date
2 2 2 date
3 2 1 date
4 2 2 date

Comment: ID(1,2,3,4), ID1(1,2,2,2), itemNumber(1,2,1,2), date(date,date,date,date). This is my four columns with four rows. itemNumber can be only 1 or 2. ID1 is primary key. I want only those ID's having itemNumber=2 and if count(itemNumber) grouped by ID is greater than 1, then my time constraint needs be changed as said in previous comments

Comment: So from that data what is your desired output?

Comment: i only need“Id’s” where “itemNumber” is 2, and then if count(ItemNumber) is 1 when grouped by "ID1" which is not primary key it should filter whole rows to date between today and today+1, otherwise if that count is 2, then filter by date between today and today+2.

Comment: What I am asking for is an example of what your data looks like, and what the output of your query should be. So based on your previous comment, what you would actually see in the output?

Comment: Lets say my date column has (11/7,11/7,11/7,11/8) and input parameter for query is 11/7, i would like to see ID(2,4) though ID-4 is in 11/8 as it satisfied condition count(itemNumber)>1 when grouped by "ID1"

Comment: If that count condition fails, i want to see only ID(2) since it is only row with that date and itemNmber=2