# List in descending order of their average with at least 2 ratings and average above 3 SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 different tables. 
Table 1 - "Ratings"

```
 movie_ID   Rating
 12100      5
 12200      4
 12100      4
 12230      5
 12200      3
 12450      4
```

And table 2 - "Movies"

```
 movie_ID  Title
 12100      ABBA
 12200      BCCA
 12230      AVDG
 12450      DLPS
```

I am trying to get the top 2 of the list based on the averages where a movie_ID has at least two ratings and the average that would be higher than 3.

I am using the following command but I dont know how to add the factors so that SQL would look for data with at least 2 ratings and an average rating higher than 3

```
 select top 2 m.movie_ID, m.title, avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
 from movies m inner join
 Ratings r>2
 on m.movie_ID = r.movie_ID
 group by m.movie_ID, m.title
 order by avg(r.rating) desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is aimed at teaching you [the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9253244/335858). Since you did `GROUP BY`, and you wish to filter by the number of ratings and the average, you need to remove `WHERE` and put the condition into `HAVING`:

```
select top 2
    m.movie_ID
,   m.title
,   avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
from movies m
inner join Ratings r on m.movie_ID = r.movie_ID
group by m.movie_ID, m.title
-- Since you are using GROUP BY, the filter goes here:
having count(*) >= 2 AND avg(r.rating) > 3
order by avg(r.rating) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on MSSQL

```
select top(2) Movies.movie_ID, Movies.Title, avg(Rating.Rating) as [Avg_Rating]
from Movies
join Rating on
    Movies.movie_ID =   Rating.movie_id and
    Rating.Rating > 1
Group by Movies.movie_ID, Movies.Title
having avg(Rating.Rating) >2
order by avg(Rating.Rating) Desc
```