# Error updating record: Invalid use of group function for updating previous all data

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "UPDATE purchase SET stat='1' WHERE `id`='$id' AND 4*(plan)<= sum(plan) ";
```

Or

```
$sql = "UPDATE purchase SET stat='1' WHERE `id`='$id' AND 4*(plan-1)<= sum(plan-1) ";
```

I am trying to make a query by this update, if summation of all row is grater than 1st row, it will update 1st row, and this rules for all row. But it is showing error and says

```
Error updating record: Invalid use of group function
```

What is the problem in this query? I need help for this error.

Comment: _Invalid use of group function_ pretty much covers it; you can't do that directly in an UPDATE; you can maybe try using a subquery, or (if that doesn't work) query for it in a separate query first. _The subquery option might not work without some hokey tricks, like wrapping the subquery in a SELECT * subquery; so I would lean toward the latter option._

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where

Comment: Can you give me an example by editing this? Thanks

Comment: @Devon doubt that'll help here; he is trying to use aggregation in an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate function like `SUM()` in the `WHERE` clause of a query, because `SUM()` is calculated over all the selected rows, but `WHERE` is used to select the rows. You need to calculate the sum in a separate query, then join it.

```
UPDATE purchase
JOIN (SELECT SUM(plan) AS plantotal FROM purchase) AS p1
    ON 4*(plan-1) <= plantotal
SET stat = '1'
WHERE id = '$id'
```

To base your update on all the rows with higher IDs, you can join with a subquery that gets totals for each group of rows.

```
UPDATE purchase AS p
JOIN (SELECT p1.id AS id, SUM(p2.plan) AS plantotal
      FROM purchase AS p1
      JOIN purchase AS p2 ON p2.id > p1.id) AS p3
ON p3.id = p.id AND 4*(p.plan-1) <= p3.plantotal
SET stat = '1'
```

Comment: Can it be possible, that, update row based on next inputs? do not accept the previous data @barmar

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you give an example?

Comment: i mean, there is row 1,2,3,4,5 and row 1 will changed based on 2,3,4,5, again row 2 will change based on 3,4,5 etc

Comment: Write a subquery that gets the sums of each set of rows, and join with that. See updated answer.

Comment: sorry for again knocking you @Barmar, it is just updating one row sir, but, i need this rules for every code

Comment: What is "code" in the query? This updates every row that matches the criteria. Update the question and show sample data and the desired result.