# mysql select max value of unique items

Tags: mysql

I have this table and need to pic the city with the max length and min length.

In this query Im trying to get the max length

[image]

```
select x.name, x.len from
(select name, char_length(name)  as len
from tutorials.city) x
where x.len = (select max(x.len) from x)
```

This query works with aggregator in where clause -

```
select x.name, x.len from
(select name, char_length(name)  as len
from tutorials.city) x
where x.len = (select max(id) from tutorials.city)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For max length :

```
select name
from tutorials.city
order by length(city) desc
limit 1;
```

For min length :

```
select name
from tutorials.city
order by length(city)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks...What is the problem with the above query? Cant I refer to the inner table on the when clause?

Comment: You can't use aggregation functions in the `WHERE` clause. Aggregation is done *after* selecting all the rows.

Comment: My query will return the longest city name.  If 2 city are equals, you'll get only one.  That's you want, or you want the 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an aggregation function in the `WHERE` clause. Aggregation isn't done until all the rows are selected, and `WHERE` is used to select the rows.

You can use `HAVING` instead.

```
select x.name, x.len from
(select name, char_length(name)  as len
from tutorials.city) x
HAVING x.len = MAX(x.len)
```

See [SQL - having VS where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)