# How to get COUNT of LEFT JOIN data

Tags: sql, dql

I'm trying to get the ChannelGroups where the ChannelGroup has a count of 0 on its relation ChannelGroupUsers.

```php
public function userEmptyChannelGroups()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT cg
                 FROM App:ChannelGroup cg
                 LEFT JOIN cg.channelGroupUsers cgu
                 WHERE COUNT(cgu) = 0'
            )
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
```

But I keep getting `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (500 Internal Server Error)` upon trying the above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate function, like `COUNT` in a `WHERE` clause. You can, however, use an aggregate function in a `HAVING` clause. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253267/8068625) for more on the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

However, if you're just trying to get the rows in `cg` that don't have any  joined rows from `cgu`, you can select where `cgu.id` is null.

For example:

```sql
SELECT cg
FROM App:ChannelGroup cg
LEFT JOIN cg.channelGroupUsers cgu
WHERE cgu.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find rows that don't have a connection to another table you can do something like this. In `where` there can be any column from table2.

```
select
    *
from table1 
left join table2
    on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.someColumn is null
```