# ERROR: aggregate may not appear in the where clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a having clause or a select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having

I have the following code (see below) that finds the minimum date of birth of an employee.

I don't understand why does it throw the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

The following code throws the previous error:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM [TerpsConsultant.Employee] e1
  WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
  FROM [TerpsConsultant.Employee] e2
  WHERE e1.empDateOfBirth = MIN(e2.empDateOfBirth)
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKHVW.png)

After searching for similar questions on here, I tried this code and it worked fine:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM [TerpsConsultant.Employee] e1
  WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
  FROM [TerpsConsultant.Employee] e2
  WHERE e1.empDateOfBirth = (SELECT MIN(e2.empDateOfBirth) FROM [TerpsConsultant.Employee] e2)
)
```

Would you help me understand why the first version of the code is not working? What's the difference after all?

Comment: error message told you the reason dy... aggregate function should be in subquery if you want to use it in where condition

Comment: Where condition is performed before the row aggregates such as MIN or MAX are evaluated. Therefore at the time of performing the filter (where) the MIN can't yet be evaluated ( its scope is not known). When you put it in a subquery, the 'WHERE` clause on that subquery -or the absence of it- defines its scope, and it can be evaluated, and then used in the be main query.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said in comments, you cannot use aggregate function in `where` clause.

As specified in [MSDN Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you can only use aggregate functions as expressions only in the following situations:

- The select list of a SELECT statement (either a subquery or an outer query).
- A HAVING clause.

So in your first statement, your code is invalid, because it doesn't meet the requirements for using aggregates. While in second statement, you have a subquery which returns the aggregate, and only then it checks on the where condition.

And as [Sergey Kalinichenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/sergey-kalinichenko) answered [on this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253267/16019058).

> `WHERE` clause introduces a condition on *individual rows*; `HAVING` clause introduces a condition on *aggregations*, i.e. results of selection where a single result, such as count, average, min, max, or sum, has been produced from multiple rows. Your query calls for a second kind of condition (i.e. a condition on an aggregation) hence `HAVING` works correctly.