# May I ask where did I go wrong with my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, average

Question:

[image: This is the question]

My Query:

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  ROUND(AVG(score), 2) AS avg_score
FROM students
WHERE test_name IN ('English Test', 'History Test')
AND score >= 0.9
GROUP BY id, first_name, last_name
ORDER BY avg_score DESC;
```

The Output:

[image: error, expected 11 rows expected]

Thanks!

To get the average os the students but I keep on getting an error :(

Comment: `GROUP BY id, first_name, last_name` should just be `GROUP BY first_name, last_name`. `id` is unique to each row so you're not combining all the scores for each student.

Comment: you should include the error in your question.   @Barmar's comment seems correct though

Comment: @BretWeinraub The error is in the second screenshot.

Comment: You must check calculated average score, not separate scores.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am color blind :) try to include the error in the text description :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include `id` in the `GROUP BY`. That's unique to each row, so you're not combining all the scores for each student.

Also, the question says you should return the student's whose *average* score is at least 0.9. You're filtering the raw scores, not the average. Use `HAVING` to filter the aggregated results. See [SQL - HAVING vs. WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where)

The instructions say that the ordering should be by the *unrounded* value, so use `ORDER BY AVG(score) DESC` rather than `ORDER BY avg_score`. It doesn't mention whether the `0.9` check should be on the rounded or unrounded value; in my code below I use the unrounded value.

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  ROUND(AVG(score), 2) AS avg_score
FROM students
WHERE test_name IN ('English Test', 'History Test')
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING AVG(score) >= 0.9
ORDER BY AVG(score) DESC;
```

Comment: This needs to be `HAVING avg(score) >= 0.9`; as is you will include students with averages >= .085

Comment: Why would that happen? `0.085` rounds to `0.08`, which is not `>= 0.90`

Comment: I guess you meant to use something like `0.899` as the example.

Comment: The instructions aren't clear about whether this check should be on rounded or unrounded values, but since they say to use unrounded for ordering, I guess we can assume the same for HAVING.

Comment: round doesn't do banker's rounding  https://dbfiddle.uk/PHnD0W8N  I see I did get the decimal place wrong

Comment: @ysth It uses banker's rounding for `FLOAT`, round away from 0 for `DECIMAL`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much! This much more make sense. :)