SQL - Putting a simple condition into HAVING instead of the WHERE clause
Is it possible to put a condition into the HAVING clause that does not use an aggregate function?
It is an error? A bad practice?
I didn't find anything online about this doubt.
Normally the HAVING clause is used with aggregate function.
But this is just an academic question. Someone told me it is WRONG!
E.g.:
SELECT continent, COUNT(*)
FROM Country
GROUP BY continent
HAVING continent = 'Europe';

I would normally put this simple condition into the WHERE clause.
But it seems to work in both ways. Same result.
The number of countries in Europe.
I know the WHERE is evaluated before the grouping and the HAVING after the grouping by the DBMS, but the result does not change, tho.
So, why would it be wrong?

what dbms are you using? pls tag it, your desired solution might depend on that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253244/sql-having-vs-where

MySQL docs points out to not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause , but not what happen if used. My guess is , WHERE and HAVING are the same with the only differences that having comes after the group and applies to groups, while where can not and the other difference where can be indexed while having can not (my guess). I do not now about other dbms

Does this answer your question? SQL - HAVING vs. WHERE

You can put other, non-grouped. columns in the WHERE clause (e.g. population).

@ErgestBasha
Thank you, your answer was the most complete, thank you for referencing the MySQL documentation.
It solves my doubt.

Note that MySQL's HAVING is a bit product specific.

The short answer is: It is not wrong (provided that what columns you have in your HAVING clause is in your GROUP BY clause). Most of the time, it would be more efficient for the query to have it in the WHERE clause.
